# Print.js and Bootstrap 4 render issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, printjs

Trying to use PrintJS to print the information in a

tag. For some reason, it refuses to render properly.

I have this:
[image: Original layout]

And when I print, I get this:
[image: Messed up printing result]

I'm printing using the following code:

```
        printJS({
            printable: 'permitDetails',
            type: 'html',
            css: ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap'
            ],
            targetStyles: false
        });
```

I have also tried using:

```
   printJS({
                printable: 'permitDetails',
                type: 'html',
                targetStyles: ['*']
            });
```

Same result for both code snippets. However, what really makes me fret is that if you check out the following Fiddle, this guys has it working perfectly?

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/rj397t4v/

Anyone knows what the issue might be?